# When zipping two lists together into a dictionary, is it possible to designate a number of values for one key?

Tags: python, list, selenium, dictionary

I'm currently working on a program in Selenium that is gathering up URLs from a website that splits it's hosted content into mirrors, each mirror containing a variable amount of parts. Due to the website in question having very unreliable CSS selectors (changes per page, basically), alongside basically no classes/IDs/names in the HTML to work with, I've rigged up a rather complicated system.

Essentially, each page delivers a variable amount of parts, anywhere from 2 to 20+. So, I've setup a part checker that scans the page for instances of the word Part (from Part 1, Part 2, Part 3, etc) and removes duplicates as a method to count how many of these parts are present across every mirror. For example, if there are 7 parts in each mirror, my code will append Part 1-Part 7 to a list and remove any duplicate mentions of other parts.

Then, assigning that list's len() to a variable, I now have a variable with an integer value equal to the number of parts for each mirror. A little complicated, but it suits my needs well enough. *Now, here is my problem:*

I have two completed lists I would like to zip together into one dictionary, one list contains the names of the mirrors and the other contains all part URLs on the page. I would like to use this len()-defined variable that I assigned previously as a guide for how many URLs I want to iterate to each mirror key. Using the example above, lets imagine a page with 7 URLs per mirror.

I want my dictionary to end up looking something like this: (Please note, the *zip code* at the top I am using is intentionally incorrect, but helps, I hope, illustrate my goal in a more roundabout way)

```
partNum = 7

mirrorDict = dict(zip(mirrorList, urlList[partNum])

mirrorDict = {Mirror1: Url1 Url2 Url3 Url4 Url5 Url6 Url7, Mirror2: Url8 Url9 Url10 Url11 Url12 Url13 Url14, Mirror3: etc...}
```

To those who took the time to read, and to answer, I thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. Most of the context for your problem is not relevant; what matters is the specific part of the overall problem that you need help with, the specific code you tried to address that part, and specifically what went wrong with that part of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mirrorList = ["m1","m2","m3"]
urlList = ["url1","url2","url3","url4","url5","url6"]
partNum = 2
mirrorDict = dict()
for i,mirror in enumerate(mirrorList):
    mirrorDict[mirror] = urlList[i*partNum : partNum*(i+1)] 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
output > mirrorDict
{'m1': ['url1', 'url2'], 'm2': ['url3', 'url4'], 'm3': ['url5', 'url6']}
```

If i understood your scenario correctly this is what you are looking for.

Also if this is not what you are looking for then please share the sample data set
for mirrorList, urlList & the traget mirrorDict, so that it would be easy to understand your usecase better.

Comment: An exceptional solution! Thank you for the assistance.